# How to provide the current user write permission for Windows system directory in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I was trying to install licence key for one software, after enterning license key,  I received error that can not save the license because access to file system is denied, please  provide the current user write permission for Windows system directory

Comment: What software are you talking about?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Your question is vague; please provide more details including the software, full error code and description and file path. Perhaps it might be as easily fixed by running it as an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise against giving everyone write permissions on this folder.  You're potentially opening your computer to malicious software.

Instead, when you run your software, hold Shift and right-click the icon.  Press "Run as Administrator".  Now enter your license details, set ay other configuration options, and quit.  Run it again normally (double-click) and make sure it all works as expected.